# I have a few questions about Damage Formulas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a damage formula that works at a basic level. Before evolving the equation I want to consider different situations:

1. There are multiple formulas at use in a RPG. If you are using a physical attack, the formula may something like ATK - DEF = DMG vs using a magic attack which could be MAG - M.DEF = DMG. Are these stored as separate a formula with each attack calling a different formula or is it a modular equation where certain values are updated to reflect what is needed?
2. Lets talk about probabilities. Imagine an attack that has a 30% chance to poison an enemy. I was going to do Random.Range (1, 100); if its a value from 1-30 then, true. Is this the .. professional way of going about it? Any recommendations?
3. In RPG damage formulas; Level is often included in the equation. Why? What does it add? I am assuming it is some kind "penalty/bonus", like if your level is to low the boss will sweep you in a few hits, but if you are close to the same level or over you will be even or sweep the boss? Currently, my formula does not have a level value.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm afraid we [can't answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) this kind of question here. StackOverflow is about the **code** (more precisely, about the **non-working code**) and not about game development in general.

Comment: well the first 2 question are about code...

Comment: You're probably better off posting this on the gamedev stackexchange or on a design related website/forum, this kind of question has no correct or incorrect answers, just opinions. What you're looking for here is discussion, not answers.

Comment: I'm not "professional" gameDev but I already can tell you their secret. The secret of the professionals is that they are much bettet at knowing their limits - knowledge/experience, imagination and time/money. They have made games before and know how difficult it is to make each and every basic game element. They know to never go for 2 types of damage when they have no experience of how to make 1 type of damage.